# how to resolve spring no bean named 'dataSource' is defined?

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, spring-security

my 'dataSource' bean is defined in dao-context.xml, like this

```
<bean name="hcpDS" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" >
                <property name="driverClassName" value="${hcp.connection.driver_class}" />
                <property name="username" value="${hcp.connection.username}" />
                <property name="password" value="${hcp.connection.password}" />
                <property name="url" value="${hcp.connection.url}" />
                <property name="maxIdle" value="${hcp.minPoolSize}" />
                <property name="maxActive" value="${hcp.maxPoolSize}" />
            </bean>
```

in security-context.xml i'm trying to use it like this:

```
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl" id="userDetailsService">
        <beans:property name="rolePrefix" value="ROLE_"/>
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <beans:property name="usersByUsernameQuery" value="SELECT username,password,enabled FROM Users WHERE username = ?"/>
        <beans:property name="authoritiesByUsernameQuery" value="SELECT u.username, a.authorityname FROM Users u JOIN Users_Authorities ua on u.id = ua.user_id JOIN Authorities a on ua.authorities_id = a.id WHERE u.username = ?"/>
    </beans:bean>
```

And have error in logs:

```
2014-06-08 16:10:06,683 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] ContextLoader - Context initialization failed

    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean] while setting bean property 'parent'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0' while setting bean property 'providers' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'userDetailsService' while setting bean property 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsService' defined in class path resource [HCP-security-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'dataSource' is defined
```

this is my applicationContext.xml in the WEB-INF Folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd">

    <import resource="classpath:HCP-security-context.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:HCP-service-context.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:HCP-dao-context.xml" />

</beans>
```

and this is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
  <display-name></display-name>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
        </listener-class>
  </listener>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
  </listener>
  <filter>
        <description>
            generated-spring-security-session-integration-filter
        </description>
        <filter-name>
            SpringSecuritySessionIntegrationFilter
        </filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
        </filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <description>generated-spring-security-filter</description>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
        </filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>
            SpringSecuritySessionIntegrationFilter
        </filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
  <filter>
    <description>generated-persistence-filter</description>
    <filter-name>hcpFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
            org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter
        </filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>entityManagerFactoryBeanName</param-name>
      <param-value>hcp</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>hcpFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>server</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>
    <param-value>com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>
  </context-param>
 <context-param>
                <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
                <param-value>sunny</param-value>
</context-param>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>template.xhtml
            </welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <description>servlet</description>
    <servlet-name>HCP Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>classpath:HCP-web-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <description>resources-servlet</description>
    <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.js.resource.ResourceServlet
        </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rename the datasource bean id with `name="dataSource"` and you have to `import dao-context.xml` inside `security-context.xml` in order to use dataSource bean.

Comment: how to import it ? you mean <!ENTITY>

Answer (score 0):

The name of the DataSource bean seems incorrect. Replace `name="hcpDS"` with `name="dataSource"`.

Comment: Are dao-context.xml and security-context.xml loaded by the ContextLoaderListener? Can you share your web.xml?

Comment: Both userDetailsService and dataSource are defined in the same ApplicationContext, so it should work. I do not see any misconfiguration in your config. Sorry I can't help more...